# vmware esx4.1 virtual disk locked after failed snapshot creation

Tags: centos, vmware-esx, virtualization

I have vmware vsphere 4 esx4.1.
I have a virtual machine with centos6 64bit OS and 3 virtual disks (50GO system/ 250 GO user data / 250 GO backup)

When I tried to take a snapshot of the VM, I got an error message like unspecifi-ed filename has bigger size than biggest size authorized by the datastore.

My problem is that the VM could not start after I got this message error because it could not get access to the 2nd and 3rd disk (only the system disk is normal). It seems that these 2 disks are locked.

I restart the physical esx machine but I had the same thing!

Could you please help! I'm realy blocked and I need your help!

Answer (score 3):

When I've encountered similar situations, I've shut the virtual machine down and navigated to the datastore containing the VM. I use NFS for most datastores, so there are lock (.lck) files that can be removed. Easy.

However, I'm assuming you're using VMFS on local storage. The process is less-transparent. VMWare has a [knowledge base article outlining the troubleshooting steps for locked VM files](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=10051). Enable SSH access to the host if you can.

```
These virtual machine files are commonly locked for runtime:

<VMNAME>.vswp
<DISKNAME>-flat.vmdk
<DISKNAME>-<ITERATION>-delta.vmdk
<VMNAME>.vmx
<VMNAME>.vmxf
vmware.log
```

Since this issue occurred during a snapshot, you'll want to focus on the `<DISKNAME>-flat.vmdk` and `<DISKNAME>-<ITERATION>-delta.vmdk` files. Either way, follow the steps listed in the [VMWare article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=10051).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to follow this link but I didn't find any locked disk!

Could the snapshot makes the disk irreadable?

In the VM I made fdisk -l and it says that it has not a valid partition table!

Comment: Were there any "delta" files in your datastore? What errors are you getting in the vSphere client console?

Comment: there are no any *delta files. It was the first time that I made a snapshot for this virtual machine

Comment: in the vspehere client there is no error! The VM runs until mounting the 2nd and 3dr disk! 

I have this message in the Centos Os VM:
<<
fsck.ext3 : Périphérique ou ressource occupée lors de la tentative d'ouverture de /dev/sdb1

Système de fichier monté ou ouvert en mode exclusive par un autre programme? >>

I could login in into the VM, but the 2nd and 3rd disk are not seem by the OS.

Comment: Now, I have this error when I start a VM : 

Motif : The destination file system does not support large files.
Impossible d’ouvrir le disque '/vmfs/volumes/4f9d56ed-dfb9f20e-00e3-d4ae52734324/hosting/hosting_1.vmdk' ou l’un des disques snapshot dont il dépend.